# How can I loop through a list of dicts, backwards, until a particular key value is found?

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dict of dicts:

```
for i in results[2]:
    print i

Recurring: {'p_pnref': 'E78P2DFEA7E3', 'p_result': '12'}
Recurring: {'p_pnref': 'E78P2E93B933', 'p_result': '0'}
Recurring: {'p_pnref': 'E35P0A5578D3', 'p_result': '12'}
Recurring: {'p_pnref': 'E24P0AA506C3', 'p_result': '24'}
Recurring: {'p_pnref': 'E25P0AFF2C43', 'p_result': '24'}
Recurring: {'p_pnref': 'E34P0B4909A3', 'p_result': '24'}
```

Im interested in the value of `p_result`. I can easily grabb the **last** entry with a `list(results[2])[-1].p_result` but what I am looking to go is, loop through the list, backwards until I land on an entry which `p_result == 0`. In this example it'd be the second line down (`p_pnref == E78P2E93B933`).

How can I accomplish this? If I could iterate the negative index I think I could figure the rest out but im not sure how to do this.

Assuming these are Recurring Payments and `0 == successful payment`, Im trying to grab "the most recent successful transaction".

Comment: If this is more than a small or quick-n-dirty project, this kind of data may be more suited to databases. SQLite plays nice with Python, has a small footprint, is very fast - and is built to do these kinds of queries

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think `reversed` is what you are looking for:

```
records = [
    {'p_pnref': 'E78P2DFEA7E3', 'p_result': '12'},
    {'p_pnref': 'E78P2E93B933', 'p_result': '0'},
    {'p_pnref': 'E35P0A5578D3', 'p_result': '12'},
    {'p_pnref': 'E24P0AA506C3', 'p_result': '24'},
    {'p_pnref': 'E25P0AFF2C43', 'p_result': '24'},
    {'p_pnref': 'E34P0B4909A3', 'p_result': '24'},
]

for record in reversed(records):
    if record['p_result'] == '0':
        print record['p_pnref']
        break
```

Comment: holllly crap. I just wrote this out myself after posting the question. Like, to the T. Nice.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly you want:

```
for i in reversed(results[2]):
    if i["p_result"] == "0":
        do_stuff(i)
```